# NestJS - communication between micro-services using service discovery

Tags: http, kubernetes, nestjs, microservices, service-discovery

I have 2 dockerized `NestJS` apps that need to communicate with one another using HTTP protocol.

One way is to use HttpModule to send http requests to the remote microservice. But with this the app needs to be aware of IP (exact urls) of the remote microservice.

1. So I wanted to use some service discovery solution - kubernetes has built in service discovery mechanism but could not find many examples on how to achieve this with kubernetes.
2. Then I found about client proxy in nestjs that can be use to refer to remote service using its name ?
3. Can we use ClientProxy for http cases. Also I think its kind of confusing that NestJS docs says `In Nest, a microservice is fundamentally an application that uses a different transport layer than HTTP.` 
   HTTP is an application layer protocol that uses TCP as Layer 4 protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like making it too complicated. Think Kubernetes think easy..!

You can directly sue the service name in each other to connect the two micro services. Although **service discovery** is a good option to implement when you can tons of **micro services**.

if you have only two micro services deployment with name **service-1** & **service-2** you can both connect to each other over this name. `http://service-1` is and `http://service-2`

**service-1.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-1
spec:
  type: clusterip
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

If you don't want to go with a third party to implement the **service discovery** you can also leverage the **Nginx**.

You can read my article : https://medium.com/@harsh.manvar111/service-discovery-with-nginx-kubernetes-999c692cd851

All services connect to each other across Kubernetes cluster with **service name**.

This is the **FQDN** : `<service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local`

You can also use this with **Kubernetes DNS** will also resolve **IP** even if get changed anytime nothing to worry: `http://<service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local`

For where is easy to understand my [Keycloak](https://github.com/harsh4870/Keycloack-postgres-kubernetes-deployment/blob/main/keycload-deployment.yaml#L44) application here trying to connect to Postgres database. Both running in same **namespace**.

So **keycloak** connecting to **Postgres** database with **service name** only directly. Here Postgres [service.yaml](https://github.com/harsh4870/Keycloack-postgres-kubernetes-deployment/blob/main/postgres.yaml) for ref.

Comment: Thanks, I created a minikube cluster and tried things out. Was able to get the service to communicate using Kubernetes DNS service discovery.